# проблемы с ролями rbac ошибка с AccessControl

Tags: yii2

вот RBAC контролер

```
class RbacController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Initial RBAC action
     * @param integer $id Superadmin ID
     */
    public function actionInit($id = null)
    {
        $auth = Yii::$app->getAuthManager();
        $auth->removeAll();
        $groupRule = new GroupRule();
        $auth->add($groupRule);
        $user = $auth->createRole('user');
        $user->description = 'User';
        $user->ruleName = $groupRule->name;
        $auth->add($user);
        $moderator = $auth->createRole('moderator');
        $moderator ->description = 'Moderator';
        $moderator ->ruleName = $groupRule->name;
        $auth->add($moderator);
        $auth->addChild($moderator, $user);
        $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
        $admin->description = 'Admin';
        $admin->ruleName = $groupRule->name;
        $auth->add($admin);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $moderator);
        if ($id !== null) {
            $auth->assign($admin, $id);
            $myadmin = User::findIdentity($id);
            $myadmin->role = $admin->name;
            $myadmin->save();
        }
        echo 'DONE';
    }
}
```

есть пользователь с id 2 и ролью moderator в SiteController вот такие правила

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                        'allow' => true,
                    ],
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['admin','moderator'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

захожу модератором ну пользователем под id 2  сразу выкидывает в ошибку 403 дебагер показывает следующее

```
exception 'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'Вам не разрешено производить данное действие.' in E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\crimea\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php:151 Stack trace: 
#0 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\crimea\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php(134): yii\filters\AccessControl->denyAccess(Object(yii\web\User)) 
#1 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\crimea\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ActionFilter.php(71): yii\filters\AccessControl->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction)) 
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\ActionFilter->beforeFilter(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#3 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\crimea\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(541): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#4 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\crimea\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(263): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent))
#5 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\crimea\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php(108): yii\base\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction)) 
#6 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\crimea\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(149): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction)) 
#7 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\crimea\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array) 
#8 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\crimea\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(84): yii\base\Module->runAction('', Array)
#9 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\crimea\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request)) 
#10 E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\crimea\backend\web\index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run() #11 {main}
```

вывел даные на роль пользователя вот

```
array(1) { 
[" moderator"]=> object(yii\rbac\Role)#119 (7) {
      ["type"]=> string(1) "1" 
      ["name"]=> string(10) " moderator" 
      ["description"]=> string(9) "Moderator" 
      ["ruleName"]=> string(5) "group" 
      ["data"]=> NULL 
      ["createdAt"]=> string(10) "1453060942"
       ["updatedAt"]=> string(10) "1453060942" }
}
```

вот такой var_dump у админа

```
array(1) { 
["admin"]=> object(yii\rbac\Role)#132 (7) {
    ["type"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["name"]=> string(5) "admin" 
    ["description"]=> string(5) "Admin" 
    ["ruleName"]=> string(5) "group" 
    ["data"]=> NULL 
    ["createdAt"]=> string(10) "1453060942" 
    ["updatedAt"]=> string(10) "1453060942" }
    }
```

не подскажите почему у модератора sitecontroller вываливается ошибка 403
 вот ещё добавил grouprule

```
class GroupRule extends Rule
```

{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public $name = 'group';

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function execute($user, $item, $params)
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $role = Yii::$app->user->identity->role;

        if  ($item->name === 'admin') {
            return $role === $item->name;
        } elseif ($item->name === 'moderator') {
            return $role === $item->name || $role === 'admin';
        } elseif ($item->name === 'user') {
            return $role === $item->name || $role === 'admin' || $role === 'moderator';
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

} ?>

Comment: `'roles' => ['admin','moderator'],`  vs `array(1) { 
[" moderator"]=` ..... может быть дело в пробеле?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский значит ошибка таже но коечто изменилось вопервых администратор стал было проваливаться в модератора но это наверно потому что If (Yii::$app->user->can('admin')) стаяло первее If (Yii::$app->user->can('moderator')) что ещё изменилось в дебаге  теперь появились такие строки 14 23:08:16.550 info yii\db\Command::query SELECT * FROM `auth_assignment` WHERE `user_id`='2'
15 23:08:16.551 info yii\db\Command::query SELECT * FROM `auth_item` WHERE `name`='admin'
16 23:08:16.552 trace yii\rbac\DbManager::checkAccessRecursive Checking role: admin

Comment: @АлексейШиманский 17 23:08:16.552 info yii\db\Command::query SELECT `data` FROM `auth_rule` WHERE `name`='group'
18 23:08:16.553 info yii\db\Command::query SELECT * FROM `auth_assignment` WHERE `user_id`='2'
19 23:08:16.554 info yii\db\Command::query SELECT * FROM `auth_item` WHERE `name`='moderator'
20 23:08:16.554 trace yii\rbac\DbManager::checkAccessRecursive Checking role: moderator
21 23:08:16.554 info yii\db\Command::query SELECT `data` FROM `auth_rule` WHERE `name`='group' и потом ошибка раньше ошибка возникала на 18 строке, а сейчас на 21 там где проверяется

Comment: @АлексейШиманский роль пользователя user но такого нет